# How to set environtment postresql schema in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter-4

I try configure this on my .env, but still... it's connect on **public** schema.

```
database.default.hostname = 192.168.1.40
database.default.database = test_dev
database.default.username = postgres
database.default.password = 123456
database.default.DBDriver = postgre
database.default.port = 5444
```

I try adding this code, **database.default.schema = rqhse** . But didn't works at all

Comment: `DBDriver = postgre` looks strange. Are you sure this shouldn't be `DBDriver = postgres`?

Comment: A connection isn't made "to a schema". The visibility of tables depend on the `search_path`. If you have all your tables in a different schema, you could simply change the search_path for your (test) user using `alter user`. **Never** use the superuser (`postgres`)  for your application tables and data.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that has worked for me is to include the schema in the model definition. For example:

```
protected $table = 'mySchema."myTable"';
```

Then you can use the controller as you like, for example:

```
$model = new MyModel($db);
$data = $model->findAll();
echo print_r($data);
```